# How to handle if condition within DataGridView columns?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am having getting an error while handling `DataGridView`. I want to insert a value inside a cell when that cell is empty so I made a code like this

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[1].Value = "")
{
    // my statement 
}
else
{ 
    // exception  statement 
}
```

But I am getting an error under `(dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[1].Value = "")`area I think I have to revise the if condition but no clue. Can any one help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

`=` is an assignment operator. And `==` for comparison.

Change your code to:

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[RowCount - 1].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "")
{
    // my statement 
}
else
{ 
    // exception  statement 
}
```

Comment: Raging Bull I tried that already its giving me an error NullreferenceException was unhanded

Comment: @user3021112: Have you tried `ToString()` as shown in my answer?

Comment: @user3021112: Go to debugging mode and make sure that the 2nd column of last row has some value.

Comment: @user3021112: Did this work? If yes, feel free to accept the answer so that it could help others in future to find the right answer.